# VMWare API, tasks

Tags: vmwaretasks

I have a Visual Basic code that does some tasks on IIS metabase.
I want to run this code so that the task is executed in another Virtual image (VMWare ESX).

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way you could convert the VBScript to .NET code that can be deployed as a web service in IIS?

Comment: Also, are the two VM's sitting on the same virtual/physical network?

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at VIX, specifically at vmrun.

If you're using Server 2 you can launch it either from the system that runs the VMs or over the network.

If you're using workstation or Server 1 you'll need to launch the script from the system that hosts the two VMs.